# Boolean behaves differently depending on file and viewport/f12 render

Tags: rendering, modifiers

I have a scene with a Boolean modifier cutting into geometry with difference, when appending both the cutter and base mesh to a different scene the Boolean works as expected. Viewport cycles render displays expected result as well.
counterclockwise starting at the bottom is the other file's cycles render, then the cycles viewport native file render, then cycles f12 render native file.

Does anyone know what the issue could be?

[image]

Comment: At first glance I'd say, the cutting object is set to be invisible in the 3D viewport, but not for rendering.

Comment: if Gordons answer doesn't help, please provide blend file so we can check it out

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann Unfortunately not the issue as I the picture from the other file has perfect operation performance. I assume it to be a bug relating to file size.

Comment: Are you applying any modifiers before the boolean that results in a different viewport vs. render poly count? e.g. Subsurface

Answer (score 0):

Problem is due to Blender being unstable at render with high polygons. Probably best to wait for a newer 2.9.3 version.